# How i send ERC20 tokens using wagmi.sh hooks (useSendTransaction)?

Tags: reactjs, web3js, erc20

How can I send ERC20 tokens (not native tokens) using wagmi.sh hooks (useSendTransaction)?

This the standard react hook :

```
import { useSendTransaction, usePrepareSendTransaction } from 'wagmi'
 
function App() {
  const { config } = usePrepareSendTransaction({
    request: { to: 'moxey.eth', value: BigNumber.from('10000000000000000') },
  })
  const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, sendTransaction } =
    useSendTransaction(config)
 
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={!sendTransaction} onClick={() => sendTransaction?.()}>
        Send Transaction
      </button>
      {isLoading && <div>Check Wallet</div>}
      {isSuccess && <div>Transaction: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

can we add data field inside the request and assign the token contract address to it as a value?

```
import { useSendTransaction, usePrepareSendTransaction } from 'wagmi'
 
function App() {
  const { config } = usePrepareSendTransaction({
    request: { to: 'moxey.eth', value: BigNumber.from('10000000000000000'), data: "contract address.." },
  })
  const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, sendTransaction } =
    useSendTransaction(config)
 
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={!sendTransaction} onClick={() => sendTransaction?.()}>
        Send Transaction
      </button>
      {isLoading && <div>Check Wallet</div>}
      {isSuccess && <div>Transaction: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use useContractWrite, but got error

```
const { config: configMoney } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: '0xdAC17...',
    abi: erc20ABI,
    chainId: 1,
    gas:    BigInt(1 * 10 ** 6))
    functionName: 'transfer',
    args: ['0x21406914D512535762.....', BigInt(1.00211 * 10 ** 18)],
    onError(error) {
      console.log('Error', error);
    }
  });

  const { write: sendMoney } = useContractWrite(configMoney);
```